# "accept rate" misleading, please correct

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, accept-rate, fun, unicorns

I don't meant to be critical, you guys are programmers, not English grammaticians, but this is obviously wrong and needs to be fixed.

Fortunately the solution is relatively simple:

[image]

Please make this improvement with as much haste as reasonable.

Comment: you misspelled *[feature-request]* ...

Comment: That's just... awesome! I would love to see that change made! Something tells me I'm not going to be very productive today...

Comment: @quack - No, this is obviously a bug.  I'm not asking for a *change* I'm asking for a *correction*.

Answer (score 1):

This should obviously be fixed in Meta first.  We have a need for more sparkly.

Answer (score 0):

We've done even *better*.  [It's not even shown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/140951).

I mean, how much more magic do you need than *invisible*?

Comment: Is it also pink?

Comment: Ouch! That's too bad.